# TiffBitmapEncoder is not retaining transparency when the incoming data comes from a JPEG image

Tags: c#, image, bitmap, tiff

This is an odd one for me. I have a procedure (legacy code) that takes in a Bitmap and exports the result in the appropriate format. I'm trying to export a [TIFF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TIFF) file (long story short, we need a lossless format and PNG nearly doubles the time spent compared to an RLE encoding). I know that TIFF does transparency, and indeed the software works if the *Target* Bitmap coming in originally came from a PNG or BMP file, whether I export it as a TIFF or as a PNG. However, if the file was a JPG, exporting it as a PNG keeps the transparency, but exporting it as a TIFF does not. What am I missing here? I'm also getting the same result if I run *Target.Save("Target.png")* versus *Target.Save("Target.tiff", ImageFormat.tiff)*.

```
public static void Save(Bitmap Target, Stream Destination, string Extension, int Quality, bool UsePadding)
{
    BitmapEncoder encoder;
    string sMetadataType = string.Empty;

    switch (Extension.ToLower())
    {
        case ".bmp":
            BmpBitmapEncoder bmp = new BmpBitmapEncoder();
            encoder = bmp;
            sMetadataType = "bmp";
            break;
        case ".jpg":
        case ".jpe":
        case ".jpeg":
            JpegBitmapEncoder jpg = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
            jpg.QualityLevel = Quality;
            encoder = jpg;
            sMetadataType = "jpg";
            break;

        case ".png":
            PngBitmapEncoder png = new PngBitmapEncoder();
            encoder = png; 
            sMetadataType = "png";
            break;

        case ".tif":
        case ".tiff":
            TiffBitmapEncoder tiff = new TiffBitmapEncoder();
            tiff.Compression = TiffCompressOption.Rle;
            encoder = tiff;
            sMetadataType = "tiff";
            break;

        default:
            throw new Exception("Invalid image extension");
    }

    Rectangle rc = new Rectangle(0, 0, Target.Width, Target.Height);
    BitmapData bmpData = Target.LockBits(rc, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

    try
    {
        int nSize = bmpData.Stride * Target.Height;

        BitmapSource src = BitmapFrame.Create(Target.Width, Target.Height, 
                                              Target.HorizontalResolution, Target.VerticalResolution, 
                                              System.Windows.Media.PixelFormats.Bgra32, null, 
                                              bmpData.Scan0, nSize, bmpData.Stride);

        BitmapMetadata meta = null;

        if (UsePadding && (encoder is JpegBitmapEncoder))
        {
            uint paddingAmount = 2048;
            meta = new BitmapMetadata(sMetadataType);
            meta.SetQuery("/app1/ifd/PaddingSchema:Padding", paddingAmount);
            meta.SetQuery("/app1/ifd/exif/PaddingSchema:Padding", paddingAmount);
            meta.SetQuery("/xmp/PaddingSchema:Padding", paddingAmount);
        }

        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(src, null, meta, null));
        encoder.Save(Destination);
    }
    finally
    {
        Target.UnlockBits(bmpData);
    }
}
```

I have a sneaking suspicion that this might have something to do with color palettes. The JPEG has 24 bits. The TIFF has 32. And I remember encountering something similar to this when working with the WebP format a few months ago.

Under other oddities, I had been testing this loss of transparency by using TiffBitmapDecoder to pull the image back into my application, and using IrfanView. I pulled the image into GIMP, and lo and behold, the transparency is present. This makes me wonder if the issue is partly the encoder (using some odd method for encoding transparency that is not picked up by the codec in Windows, or in IrfanView) and partly the decoder (for being unable to read in said unusual transparency).

Comment: JPEG images don't support transparency.

Comment: @MarkSetchell: No, they don't. However, I was expecting that, if I import a JPEG into a Bitmap object that does support transparency, and then perform actions that change the Alpha channel for a section of the image, that transparency will be reflected when I encode the Bitmap. It does if I encode into PNG, or into TIFF when the original file was not a JPG, but not for an imported JPG that was modified with transparency before exporting to a TIFF.

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with C#, I was just making a general observation as sometimes folks on StackOverflow don't seem to realise they can't store transparency in JPEGs.

Comment: So we know for a fact that the input bitmap has no transparency.  What do you expect to become transparent in the output bitmap?  Is there a call to Bitmap.MakeTransparent() somewhere that we can't see?

Comment: @HansPassant: In between, I do an operation that renders parts of the bitmap transparent, which is also why it is Argb32 PixelFormat by the time I see it. And I am able to get the transparency when I export the file to a PNG, or, bizarrely enough, if the input file was not a JPG. I'll try importing another format without transparency, modifying it, and seeing what I get.

Comment: I don't even see how this code can work - if you opened from a jpeg your Bitmap object is RGB24, and you just dump that raw RGB24 data into a BitmapSource object only specifying its _intended_ format, but not the format of the actual _input_ data. Furthermore, in the LockBits part you hardcode ARGB32 while the input is not guaranteed to be that.